# Possible to instantly output the return of PHP function get_class

Tags: php, oop, variables

Hello quick and simple one, just wondering if its possible to output all in one line rather then having to create a variable to store it in first.

eg my current code

```
<?php           
$className = get_class();
$className::CheckCreated();
?>
```

What I was hoping to do all in one line, or similar.

```
<?php           
get_class()::CheckCreated();
?>
```

Cheers and Merry Christmas.

Comment: Maybe with `{}` or `eval()` but what would be the benefit? One line less code?

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering. Trying to keep code as tight and clean as possible.

Comment: not currently possible afaik, this bugs me in my code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be available in PHP 7. For more information see the [Uniform Variable Syntax RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax).